# RabbitMQ slow consumer causing queue pileup in spring boot rabbitmq integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am consuming one queue with below configurations :

```
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
            final CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    
            connectionFactory.setUsername("abc");
            connectionFactory.setPassword("mnp");
            connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("xyz");
            connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
            connectionFactory.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
            return connectionFactory;
        }
    
    @Bean(name = "vmConnectionThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
        public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
                ThreadPoolTaskExecutor vmConnectionStatusExecuter =  new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
                vmConnectionStatusExecuter.setCorePoolSize(10);
                vmConnectionStatusExecuter.setMaxPoolSize(30);
                vmConnectionStatusExecuter.setQueueCapacity(10000);
                vmConnectionStatusExecuter.setThreadGroupName("vmConnectionThreadPoolTaskExecutor");
                vmConnectionStatusExecuter.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r,
                                                  ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
                        try {
                            long waitMs = 250;
                            Thread.sleep(waitMs);
                        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                            LOGGER.info("Rejected vmConnectionThreadPoolTaskExecutor thread {} ", r.getClass().getName());
                        }
        
                        executor.execute(r);
                    }
                });
                vmConnectionStatusExecuter.setKeepAliveSeconds(20);
                vmConnectionStatusExecuter.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
                vmConnectionStatusExecuter.initialize();
                return vmConnectionStatusExecuter;
            }
    
    
    
        @Bean
            public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
                SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
                factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
                factory.setAfterReceivePostProcessors( m -> {
                    m.getMessageProperties().setContentType(MEDIA_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON);
                    return m;
                });
                factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.NONE);
                factory.setConcurrentConsumers(10);
                factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(30);
                factory.setAutoStartup(true);
                return factory;
            }

@RabbitListener(queues = {"${queue}"}, containerFactory = RABBIT_LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY)
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
            process(message);
}


 @Async("vmConnectionThreadPoolTaskExecutor")
public void  process(String message){
        //insert in mysql database
}
```

Producer is sending 5K messages per second but consumer is slow and unable to handle high volume. I am running multiple consumers. This is causing pileup in the rabbitmq queue (large number of messages waiting in rabbitmq to get consumed and this keep increasing exponentially. Produced 2K messages/second through jmeter in rabbitmq and approx 120K messages were in the ready to consume/waiting state after 15 minutes of load test activity). How can we solve this issue to expect load more than 20K per second?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you expect.. If the messages are produced faster than consumed, they will pile up. You may try to find where is the bottleneck. If DB is unable to write fast enough, than using multiple consumers will actually slow the processing down due to DB locking. But you need to find the real culprit first

Comment: @gusto2 I disabled writing into database but still pileup occurs. My expectation is how to scale message consumption or find out real culprit of the issue other than database. Using 8 Core and 32 GB RAM system. There are always enough resource until pileup happens.

Comment: Just to make sure, what do you mean by "pileup"? You ran out of memory? Then what the profiler shows?

Comment: @gusto2 I meant large number of messages waiting in rabbitmq to get consumed and this keep increasing exponentially. Produced 2K messages/second through jmeter in rabbitmq and approx 120K messages were in the ready to consume/waiting queue after 15 minutes of load test activity.